# 'Not all code paths return a value ' Angular

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I am building a small project and I am basically dealing with Adding an Angular route guard. I ran into the error 'Not all code paths return a value.' What could be wrong? I am new to development.

**auth.guard.ts**

```js
     import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
     import { AccountService } from './../_services/account.service';
     import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, RouterStateSnapshot, UrlTree } from 
     '@angular/router';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

     @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
     })
     export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
     constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private toastr: 
          ToastrService) { }

          canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
         return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
          map(user => {
           if (user) {
          return true;
           }
          this.toastr.error('Access Denied');
           }
           )
          )
        }

     }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```js
    import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
    import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
    import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
    import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
    import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
      {path: 'members', component: MemberListComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
      {path: 'members/:id', component: MemberDetailComponent} ,
      {path: 'lists', component: ListsComponent} ,
      {path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent} ,
      {path: '**', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}  
    
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is a screenshot of the **auth.guard.ts**[image: 1]
The app-routing.module.ts file[image: 2]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing returning `false` if user is not available or invalid or null or whatever like this.

```
if (user) {
  return true;
}
else return false; // add this line
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two code paths, one for the true branch of the `if` and one for the false branch. The false branch doesn't return anything, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because you are return value only if user exists and if user is empty then nothing is returned.

`rxjs` map should always return value in all case

```js
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
    map(user => !!user),
    tap(user => user || this.toastr.error('Access Denied'); )
  )
}
```

I belive this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue. This was due to compiler expecting `return` statement there but sometimes all conditions does not match, hence we see this warning/message in vs code.

To overcome with this message you can simple turn off this from `tsconfig.json` by adding below line in `tsconfig.json` file

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  "noImplicitReturns": false, <== setting false will prevent warning
  ...
}
```